# Android phones showing North Direction incorrectly in Compass

Tags: android, android-location

I am implementing the navigation directions using compass. I use FusedLocationApi to find Azimuth, bearing for every location update. The compass has a North pointer. I have another compass app downloaded from play store. My app and the app from the play store shows the north directions correctly (the direction matches between 2 apps) in Samsung S6 phone (Android 5.1). I installed my app in LG Nexus (Android 6). But Nexus phone shows North direction incorrectly. Just the North direction is incorrect in Nexus but otherwise the distance calculation is fine. Why is this? I followed this [app](https://github.com/michaldrabik/CompassNav)

Comment: do both apps on the nexus point to the same wrong direction, or only yours?

Comment: I am having issues only with LG Nexus. Samsung works fine.

Comment: That was not, what I asked for. Do you have one app on the nexus, which shows north correctly? Otherwise you might have to calibrate  the compass on the nexus

Comment: Sorry.. I have little experience with Compass. But what I did is I downloaded Compass app from play store on both Nexus and Samsung. I installed my app in both phones. I kept the phones side by side in the same direction. When I open my android app in each of the phones, the North dir is showing in diff way in each phone (Like one phone shows downwards whereas the other phone shows upwards slightly on right hand side). I tried to verify this direction in Compass app that I downloaded from play store, surprisingly, each phone matches the north direction with compass app downloaded from PS

Answer (score 0):

Check if compass correct work on Nexus? LG Nexus have large amount of issues with compass. (Some of them can be fixed with collibration)